# How to extract raster information by using point shapefile in r?

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff

I would like to extract values of multiple Geotiff image by using multiple points shapefile and organize the results in a time series.

I have this:

```
library(raster); library(rgeos); library(rgdal);library(maptools)
shps <- dir(getwd(), "*.shp")
list.shape<-list()
for (shp in shps){ #Import individual point shape files
  list.shape[[shp]]<- readShapeSpatial(shp)
}
tifPs <- dir(getwd(), "*.tif")

P<-matrix(,nrow=length(tifPs), ncol=length(shps)) #To store each pixel value along the time.
list.tifP<-list(); r.vals <-list()
for (tif in tifPs){#Import G`enter code here`eotiff files.
  list.tifP[[tif]]<- rotate(raster(tif))
  r.vals[[tif]]<- extract(list.tifP[[tif]], list.shape) 
}
```

But when I run it, it shows me this error message: `Error in round(y) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function`

Any idea of how to do this?

**EDIT:**

Following the advises in the comment box, I attach [my files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BxsusuHqh4irNEFIV3Z4Q2k5LTQ?usp=sharing). What I have to do is to extract the pixel information in each raster image (Geotiff files) by using the attached point shapefile and then put all of those time series in an array.

I tried juts to extract the pixel information but the code failed.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).  This doesn't appear to be a GIS issue, though it doesn't seem to even be related to your code, either.  Please **edit** the question to identify the location of the error.

Comment: @Vince I may be misreading your comment, but I believe this is well within the scope of our site. I've seen this error before and I recall it is derived from a one of the functions in the script--I just can't remember which one.

Comment: Please consider adding some sample data in order to make this code reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
r.vals[[tif]]<- extract(list.tifP[[tif]], list.shape)
```

it looks like you are trying to extract the values from a *list* of spatial points objects (`list.shape`). I can duplicate this error using the example objects from `help(extract)`:

```
> extract(r,sp)
[1] 626 554 482 410 338 266 194 122  50

> extract(r,list(sp,sp))
Error in round(y) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

You need to loop over your spatial points in `list.shape` and extract each one individually. So you need a nested loop - an outer loop of rasters and an inner loop of spatial points. You can do this without needing a `for` loop with an `lapply` over a list of spatial points objects:

```
> lapply(list(sp,sp),function(s){extract(r,s)})
[[1]]
[1] 626 554 482 410 338 266 194 122  50

[[2]]
[1] 626 554 482 410 338 266 194 122  50
```

then its your job to do whatever you need with that output to get it into the matrix or whatever dataframe you want as your final output.

Comment: Is This line `lapply(list(sp,sp),function(s){extract(r,s)})` inside the loop?

Comment: You can't use that as it stands. That is a way of extracting raster data from locations in a number of SP point objects. If you put *something like that* inside your single loop over rasters then you need to write the code to convert the list of vectors (above, a list of two vectors) into the array form you nned.